# Free proxies not sending server response

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I'm trying to do webscrapping using free proxies and requests library in Python but I can not access server response.

I get proxy list from an URL then test each proxy checking its response, Here is an example :

```
try:
    resp = requests.get('http://example.com', proxies=proxy)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        working_proxies.append(proxy)
except:
    pass
```

But then when I have to use theses proxies from `working_proxies`, I get a 200 response status code but I can't access server response, I checked `resp.text`, `resp.headers` but I can't find it, instead I get a html page which seems to be from a provider or some randoms ads, here is a typical response header I get :

> {'Server': 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Mon, 24 Jul 2023 13:23:04
> GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 01 Aug 2021
> 12:07:32 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection':
> 'keep-alive', 'ETag': 'W/"61068e84-264"', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

However, you might tell me that I can't rely on these free proxies, but if it returns a 200 response code doesnt it means that it sucesfully accomplished the request ? I'm just wondering if there is a specific way to access response from these proxies or if they are just scamming. Thanks

Comment: Use free proxies entirely at your own risk. Don't expect reliability or performance. Do expect unreliability, poor performance and possible devious activity. If you really need a proxy then pay for it (from a reliable provider)

Comment: That's right, I know the low performance of free proxies, but that's the only way I can get a lot of proxies to try out my application. Actually, I took a small offer from a reliable provider (Webshare), but half of the proxies they give me always lead to a 403 error, so I'm not confident to take a bigger offer if I'm not sure about the efficiency of these proxies for my purpose you know

Comment: Are you sure that the 403 errors were due to the proxy?

Comment: Yes, since when I remove the proxies parameters I have normal 200 responses, I checked the response I get when I use webshare proxies and I get a page saying "Checking your browser..."